# Can't assign "keyof EntityType" as a key to "key in keyof EntityType" object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a generic function which accepts a type of an object - `EntityType`. The first parameter of this function, `defaultSortColumn`, should be a key of this `EntityType` object. So, for example, if the object has the following structure:

```js
type User = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const user: User = {
  name: 'Scott Pilgrim',
  age: 24,
};
```

Then, the first parameter of the function should accept only these two string values: `name` and `age`.

The second parameter of the function `defaultSortDirection` is a value from `SortDirections` enum:

```js
enum SortDirections {
  ASC = 'ASC',
  DESC = 'DESC',
}
```

Inside the function I wish to create an object `columns`, which property's key is the key of `EntityType` and value is one of `SortDirections`'s values. So I use the following approach:

```js
export const useSorting = <EntityType>(defaultSortColumn: keyof EntityType, defaultSortDirection: SortDirections = SortDirections.DESC) => {
  const columns: { [key in keyof EntityType]?: SortDirections } = { [defaultSortColumn]: defaultSortDirection };

  // ...
};
```

Yet, object `{ [defaultSortColumn]: defaultSortDirection }` for some reason is considered being of `{ [x: string]: SortDirections; }` type, rather than `{ [key in keyof EntityType]?: SortDirections }` as I think it should and I get the following error message:

> Type '{ [x: string]: SortDirections; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key in keyof EntityType]?: SortDirections | undefined; }'.ts(2322)

Is there a way to properly type an object's key without `as` type assertion?

Comment: This is [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948); computed property keys get widened to `string`, which is too wide for your purposes.  The only way to deal with it is equivalent to a type assertion like maybe [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w6VLYw) using the `kv` helper function from the linked github issue. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for the link and please post an answer so I can accept it. It is sad that every solution in the thread either requires `any` or type assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in TypeScript, discussed at [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).

If you have a string `key` and use it as a [computed property key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) like `const obj = {[key]: value}`, then unless the type of `key` is a single known string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), it will get widened all the way to `string` and your object will have a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) like `const obj: {[x: string]: Value}`.  So if `key` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string literal types like `"a" | "b"`, or a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type like `K extends string`, or a *pattern template literal* like `` `abc${string}` `` (as implemented in [ms/TS#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)), or anything other than a single string literal type like `"a"`, it will be widened to `string` and the object will get a string index signature.

Hence the error

```
export const useSorting = <E,>(col: keyof E, dir: SortDirections) => {
  const columns: { [K in keyof E]?: SortDirections } = { [col]: dir }; // error!
  // Type '{ [x: string]: SortDirections; }' is not assignable to type 
  // '{ [K in keyof E]?: SortDirections | undefined; }'.(2322)
};
```

Where you can see that `keyof E` has been widened to `string` and thus the object literal is of the type `{[x: string]: SortDirections}`.

---

Currently there's no great way to deal with it.  While widening all the way to `string` isn't great, it's fairly simple.  The "correct" thing to do instead isn't obvious, since different use cases warrant different types, and most of these types can have very bad performance problems when applied to even moderately-sized unions.  So we might be stuck with this for the foreseeable future.

If you're only doing this sort of thing once or twice, I'd recommend just using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and moving on:

```
const columns = { [col]: dir } as { [K in keyof E]?: SortDirections };
```

If you find yourself running into the issue a lot and have some idea what you'd like to see happen instead, you can wrap computed property creation in a helper function with whatever typing you want, and you can confine the type assertion to that one function.  One version I use is

```
function kv<K extends PropertyKey, V>(k: K, v: V):
  { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: V } }[K] {
  return { [k]: v } as any
}
```

which distributes the `Record` operation over unions in `K` (so that instead of `Record<K1 | K2, V>` you'd get `Record<K1, V> | Record<K2, V>`.  This seems to work for your example code:

```
const columns: { [K in keyof E]?: SortDirections } = kv(col, dir);
```

although it might not be the optimal typing either.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAdgQwFsIAuKOYRAS1wHMBubKfW0vAV0ICMlGBfTJgDGAe1wUo7BIjLwkqDEwLEyAcgDKo4MCgAFKgBta1QqoA0TFmwBMAFgt9GgiLk5R1IxMAAiVRBCFgKjE4RRwAQXUAYQVVSKjzJm8AUWjYlOjEgUwAM3ZcQODcKABrADcAHgBpKAgAD2AXABNQ3UQRSC8QKogQMygANQA+AAoSsir+srIBgEoSJnQoAG1dKBooKoBdMiXlgEV14t0dwag+c+XtsKh-YHZEYr2S07Lz5lD8XBBMbPqwTw6UTiHRSCAeLw0WgKCrJMyjUQGMglXoiHJQOFQJp+MgQnx+AJBEKzVBDG7AiSIzjiAAMuxWNQ2KJAaIxWwA-LjAb5-IUQu80HtEadschHFAAPQS2qIdqIACETClUAAKuBoKo9nUyBRqHRTnieYSinB6OdVOtQrgRDp8HA4FRaAQuAZoMARFBQJAoErpZqGUdSqj0ckOVyvEa+eIoAAfSS4JoQHI0CBNM18VQAOhG1gAzNZrLNBDgKUCRAZqXAAIwKIXlkV+d52jABpnBtmc9zcglR0KOYtQUuD8uV+lXQPM1mhzuGntE6MXNDlEaI-qi2aMHDKzM735OTBAA)